# Могу ли я заменить все mysql_ функции mysqli_ функциями?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Я использовал `mysql_query()` в моем проекте; но я только что узнал, что `mysql_`
 устарел с PHP 5.5, был удален в PHP 7.

Итак, я хотел бы узнать, могу ли я просто заменить все функции `mysql_` на `mysqli_`в моем проекте? Например, просто заменив `mysql_query()` на `mysqli_query()`. Есть ли какие-либо неблагоприятные последствия?

[Источник](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26476162/10719456)

Comment: Ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26476162/can-i-blindly-replace-all-mysql-functions-with-mysqli

Comment: Разве есть хоть одна причина сейчас не использовать PDO ?

Comment: @zalex Я то не спорю, но это же перевод.

Comment: О, пардон, сразу не понял вопрос.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Краткий ответ - **нет**, функции не эквивалентны.

Но зато есть инструмент для конвертации, который поможет вам, если у вас есть много вызовов функций или проектов, которые нужно изменить. Это позволит вашим скриптам работать сразу.

https://github.com/philip/MySQLConverterTool

Это раздвоенная версия оригинальной версии Oracle, и она кошерная.

Тем не менее, не так уж сложно обновить ваш код, и вы все равно можете перейти на объектно-ориентированную методологию ...

**1) Связь**

Для всех целей вам нужна новая функция соединения, которая, например, сохраняет соединение как переменную PHP;

```
$mysqli = new mysqli($host,$username,$password,$database);
```

Обратите внимание, что я сохранил соединение используя `$mysqli`.
Вы можете сохранить `$db` или как угодно, но вы должны использовать это в коде для ссылки на соединение.

Не забудьте проверить на наличие ошибки подключения;

```
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) echo "Error - Failed to connect to MySQL: " . $mysqli->connect_error;
```

**2) Запрос**

*Примечание. Необходимо защищать от внедрения SQL с помощью подготовленных операторов, доступных в MySQLi. Посмотрите [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/3899908), но я просто собираюсь показать основы.*

Теперь вам нужно включить соединение в качестве аргумента в ваш запрос и другие `mysqli_` функции. В процедурном коде это первый аргумент, в ООП вы пишете это как метод класса;

Процедурный:

```
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli,$sql);
```

OOП:

```
$result = $mysqli->query($sql);
```

**3) Получить результат**

Получение результата аналогично старой `mysql_` функции в процедурном;

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
```

но так как `$result` теперь объект в MySQL, вы можете использовать вызов функции объекта;

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
```

**4) Закрыть соединение**

Как и прежде, вам нужно включить соединение в функцию `mysqli_close`; в качестве аргумента в процессуальном;

```
mysqli_close($mysqli);
```

и как объект, на котором вы запускаете функцию в OOП;

```
$mysqli->close();
```

Посмотрите [документацию](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) для получения дополнительной информации. Не забудьте преобразовать любые функции закрытия соединения, освобождения результата или подсчета ошибок и строк, которые у вас есть.

Основное правило - для функций, которые используют соединение с базой данных, вам необходимо включить его в функцию сейчас (либо в качестве первого аргумента в процедурном, либо в объект, который вы используете для вызова функции в OOП), либо для набора результатов вы можете просто изменить функцию `mysqli_` или использовать результирующий набор в качестве объекта.

[Источник](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26476208/10719456)

Comment: «много звонков» — потрачено!

Comment: @andreymal Блин, не заметил, сейчас поправлю.

Comment: @andreymal Поправил, просто я в первый раз перевожу :)